# React underline react-bootstrap NavItem when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make a webpage where I have a react-bootstrap navbar with a few Nav items. I want to scroll through the page so that when I go to a new section, that particular NavItem is underlined or when I click on that NavItem, it automatically scrolls me through to that item.
I tried looking online and found react-scroll but do not know how to link it to my react-bootstrap code.

This is my Navbar Component

```
export const NavbarComponent = () => {
    return (
      <>
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect className="style-navbar">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand className="style-navbrand" href="/">
              <div class="inl">LOGO</div>
              <div className="style-subheading"Subheading</div>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="style-nav">
          <Nav.Item className="style-navitem">
            <Nav.Link className="style-navlink" href="/home">ABOUT</Nav.Link>
           </Nav.Item>
           <Nav.Item className="style-navitem">
            <Nav.Link className="style-navlink" href="/members">MEMBERS</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item className="style-navitem">
            <Nav.Link className="style-navlink" href="/pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
          <Nav>
              <Nav.Link id="style-navlink" href="/contact">CONTACT</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      </>
```

This is my App.js

```
  return (
    <div className="style-background">
      <div className = "style-backg-sheet">
        <NavbarComponent/>
        <AboutComponent/>
        <MemberComponent/>
        <PricingComponent/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

AboutComponent

```
import React from 'react'
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';

const About = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

I basically wanted to have different sections as above on one page where if I click on a particular navbar item, it underlines that item and scrolls me down to it (if I click on Pricing, it scrolls me down to the pricing section which has a bit of text and pictures).

Comment: Are you trying to link to "pages" you are rendering on different routes, or are you trying to use hash links to link to and scroll into view sections on the same page?

Comment: The second one, using hash links to link and scroll to view sections on the same page

Comment: Try links like `href="#home"` and `href="#members"` to link to the anchor tags on the page. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] that includes what you are trying to link to on the page?

Comment: Yes, I added my App.js page which has different components

Comment: Can you add `AboutComponent`, `MemberComponent`, and `PricingComponent` code to your post so we ca see what is targetable?

Comment: Sure, I have not added the text yet but it is pretty much text/pictures inside a container

Answer (score 0):

If all you want, at-a-minimum, is for the links to navigate to a specific section and underline the active menu item then I suggest the following:

- Assign an `id` attribute to each "section" you care to link to.

  ```
  const About = () => {
    return (
      <div className="section" id="about"> // <-- add id for each section
        <Container>
          <h1>About</h1>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  };
  ```
- Use a hashlink in the nav items

  ```
  <Nav.Link className="style-navlink" href="#about">
    About
  </Nav.Link>
  ```
- Add the CSS to style the active menu item link

  ```
  a.style-navlink.active {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  ```

[image]

[image: Edit react-underline-react-bootstrap-navitem-when-scrolling-down]

This will scroll the sections into view so long as everything is rendered inline as a single continuous document. What I see when trying to make the navbar "sticky" or "fixed" to the top so it doesn't scroll with the content, the rest of the content needs to be placed in a scrollable container and the default "scrolling-to" behavior breaks. You can fix this with third-party libraries. In this next section I chose `react-router-hash-link` to create hashlinks that have control over how content is scrolled to.

```
import { NavHashLink } from "react-router-hash-link";

...

<Nav.Link
  activeClassName="active-link" // <-- define active classname
  as={NavHashLink}              // <-- render NavHashLink component
  className="style-navlink"
  smooth                        // <-- smooth scrolling
  to="#about"
>
  About
</Nav.Link>

...
```

```
.active-link {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit react-underline-react-bootstrap-navitem-when-scrolling-down (react-router-hash-link)]